# How increment value in hidden_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I create a new answer of a Poll, I need to increase the value by one of a hidden_field :sequence . What do I need to add in the value in hidden_field?

```
.poll_row
  .poll_item
    = f.input :answer, input_html: { class: 'ctrlenter expanding' }, label: false, placeholder: 'Введите вариант ответа'
    = f.hidden_field, :sequence, value:??????   
    = button_tag 'вверх', type: 'button', class: 'up_id', value: 'up'
    = button_tag 'вниз', type: 'button', class: 'down_id', value: 'down'
    - if @poll.editable?(current_user)
      = link_to_remove_association "remove", f, { wrapper_class: 'poll_item' }
```

Comment: Maybe you should fetch all poll_items and set the ID of each item to the sequence

Comment: no, i need add value in column sequence

Comment: Is the `sequence` persisted in your `polls` table?

Comment: Table poll_item have column sequence. When I create new poll_item for poll need increment +1 starting from 1

Comment: You do not get the poll_item from the database? In that case you should just set the sequence via js maybe. I feel that there is not enough information to help you properly, maybe you can elaborate on your issue.

Comment: Do you mean you need to add a unique item to Poll, I guess you can use uuid, or you can just set that value auto increment in database, so that, you do not have to worry about that value.